# How to write devanagari letter 'dnya'?

Tags: input-language, special-characters, input-method

I am trying to write Devanagari letter dnya  which is in word "dnyan"(ज्ञान) means knowledge.

Ex. संत ज्ञानेश्वर (Saint Dnyaneshwar)

I have installed both inscript and KaGaPa Phonetic(Devanagari) input Methods. But am not able to write it after so many attempts. This letter is missing in Character Map also.

(I have copied the above letter from wikipedia. It is not a good practice to copy it every time from elsewhere.)

If somebody knows this, please answer my question as I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make that comment an answer. You can answer your own question

Answer (score 4):

Got it... j + f + z with KaGaPa Phonetic input method i.e. ज + ् + ञ = ज्ञ . May this be useful to somebody else....